# Invorking fillInStackTrace method after invoked printStackTrace method

Tags: java, exception

Blow is a example copied from Think in Java 4 edition

```
   public class Rethrowing {
        public static void f() throws Exception {
            System.out.println("originating the exception in f()");
            throw new Exception("thrown from f()");
        }

        public static void h() throws Exception {
            try {
                f();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Inside h(),e.printStackTrace()");
                e.printStackTrace(System.out); //first print line           throw (Exception) e.fillInStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                h();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("main: printStackTrace()");
                e.printStackTrace(System.out);
            }
        }
    }


Output:
originating the exception in f()
Inside h(),e.printStackTrace()
java.lang.Exception: thrown from f()
    at Rethrowing.f(Rethrowing.java:20)
    at Rethrowing.h(Rethrowing.java:25)
    at Rethrowing.main(Rethrowing.java:35)
main: printStackTrace()
java.lang.Exception: thrown from f()
    at Rethrowing.f(Rethrowing.java:20)
    at Rethrowing.h(Rethrowing.java:25)
    at Rethrowing.main(Rethrowing.java:35)

When comment //first print line

Output:
originating the exception in f()
Inside h(),e.printStackTrace()
main: printStackTrace()
java.lang.Exception: thrown from f()
    at Rethrowing.h(Rethrowing.java:29)
    at Rethrowing.main(Rethrowing.java:35)
```

My question is why i first invoke e.printStackTrace(printOut out ) method before the fillInStackTrace  mehod, and then the fillInStackTrace seems not available. Any one can do me a faver, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

user917879, When you call `e.fillInStackTrace();` it resets the StackTrace. So, to print the current StackTrace - before it is get reset - you need to invoke the e.printStackTrace(printOut out ) first.

Comment: Thanks,for your comment, but my mean is that if i call e.printStackTrace() before e.fillInStackTrace() the cause line not start at "throw (Exception)e.fillInStackTrace() " line, but start at the orignal "throw new Exception("thrown from f()")" line. so i don't know why it would happen?

Comment: Yes, Because the first Exception("thrown from f()") is occured when calling f() in h() and thrown.
And it is caught by the catch in the h() and first StackTrace is printed.
Then, StackTrace is get reset and the Exception throws.
It is caught by the catch in main() and print the second StackTrace in there.
Here when calling "throw (Exception) e.fillInStackTrace();" the Stack is get reset. But the exception occured doesn't change.
So although the Stack's top point changed to Rethrowing.java:15 (at SOF.Rethrowing.h(Rethrowing.java:15)) the thrown Exception "thrown from f()" is passing as it was.

Comment: Billion thanks, but i still do not understand what is "StackTrace is get reset" means, do u mean that when i call e.printStackTrace(),it has already do reset the operation "fill StakTrace",so it would not availble when call e.fillInStackTrace() next. that's right?

Comment: As you know, in a call stack, the last method called is at the top of the stack and the first method called is in the bottom. 
Then, if an exception occured in some method, it will propagate from top to bottom of the call stack untill it is caught at some point.
So, when you catch the exception and call the e.printStackTrace() it shows how the call stack looks like from the point that the exception occured.
So, when you call the fillInStackTrace it will change this "point that the exception occured" to the line that the e.fillInStackTrace(); called.
This is the meaning of the StackTrace Reset.